# Oracle : SQL using REGEXP_LIKE

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to extract string from a value of a cell in Oracle table. How can I do that?

```
VALUE
--------
/var1/var2/var3/C751994ZP1QT11/var4.itp
```

I want to extract "C751994ZP1QT11" from the value using SQL. I searched some function like REGEXP_LIKE,  but I am not quite understand how to use it.

Thanks ahead for the help.

Comment: Thanks all for the answer, :) just made a mistake, there is no ** in between. Please see correction above.

Comment: So what is the criteria? Do you want the 3rd folder name? Do you want the last folder name before the file name? The existing answers show how to extract strings, so you should be able to figure it out. But if you can't, no one can show you how unless you are more specific as to your requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to extract a string, you need to use `regexp_substr()`. `regexp_like()` would return a boolean indicating if a certain regular expression matches your string, while `regexp_substr()` actually returns the matched string.

In your case, assuming you want the string between `/**` and `**/`, you could use something like this:

```
select 
  regexp_substr(
    '/var1/var2/var3/**C751994ZP1QT11**/var4.itp', 
    '/\*\*.*\*\*/') 
from dual
```

Refer [here](http://psoug.org/reference/regexp.html) for some useful shortcuts on regular expressions with Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE('/var1/var2/var3/**C751994ZP1QT11**/var4.itp','.*\*\*(.*)\*\*.*','\1') result from dual
```